# What should be the dimensions of title bar of an app according to IBM carbon design system?

Tags: user-interface, adobe-xd, carbon-design-system

I am designing the UI of an app using IBM CDS. It gives the style guide for all items but, I couldn't find the dimensions of a title bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the IBM Carbon docs, it seems like the height of the UI shell header (or what you referred to as title bar) should be 48px or 3rem.

Source: https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/UI-shell-header/style